# how to convert NSData UTF8 encoded data to UTF16

Tags: ios, utf-8, nsdata, utf-16

I am receiving some data from my database its UTF8 encoded. I would like to know how to take this NSData thats UTF8 and re-encode it in UTF16?

is there any way to do this? I know how to do it when passing a NSString to NSData

```
[@"myString" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

But I am not entirely sure how or if its even possible to do without having to put it into a string first...

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you particularly object to converting it to a string first (obviously by decoding it as UTF-8)?

Comment: well I'm not to sure on the pro's and con's of doing so.. I have tried to read up on this type of thing but havent really found alot of information regarding what I am trying to do. I guess if its the only way they I will have to do it like that.

Comment: It seems the *natural* way to do it to me, certainly.

Comment: okay.. so something like this then **NSString *tempConversion = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *convertedData = [tempConversion dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];**

Comment: As a side note: `NSUTF16StringEncoding` always prepends a byte-order marker to the output. If you don't want that, use `NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding` or `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding`.